# Unique values in particular column only 2-d array (using numpy)

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a `2-d` array in `numpy`. I wish to obtain unique values *only in a particular column.*

```
        import numpy as np
        data = np.genfromtxt('somecsvfile',dtype='str',delimiter=',')

        #data looks like
        [a,b,c,d,e,f,g],
        [e,f,z,u,e,n,c],
        ...
        [g,f,z,u,a,v,b]
```

Using `numpy/scipy` only, how do I obtain an array or list of unique values in the 5th column. (I know it can easily be done with pandas.)

The expected **output** would be 2 values: `[e,a]`

Comment: `np.unique(data[:, 4])`?

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer posted. A simple referencing question in essence.

np.unique(data[:, 4])

With thanks.